# Display percentage saving in Woocommerce category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display a percentage value of the total saving if a product is on sale in Woocommerce.

The part I'm having a problem with is actually accessing the value so I can work out the percentage.
I need to access `sale_price` and `regular_price` but cannot seem to get around `data:protected`

If I dump the product array then I have this:

```
   object(WC_Product_Simple)#11777 (12) {
  ["object_type":protected]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["post_type":protected]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["cache_group":protected]=>
  string(8) "products"
  ["data":protected]=>
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "249.53"
    ["regular_price"]=>
    string(6) "349.99"
    ["sale_price"]=>
    string(6) "249.53"
```

Ideally I'd like to assign the values i want to a  variable so i could work out the percentage like this:

```
$percentage_saving = number_format(((($sale_price - $regular_price) / $regular_price) * 100), 0);
```

**EDIT:**

For anyone who might find it helpful, this is the code that worked for me:

```
$sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
$regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();

$percentage_saving = number_format(((($sale_price - $regular_price) / $regular_price) * 100), 0);
```

Comment: Is the Wc_Product_Simple has getters ? getData maybe ?

Comment: @Hooli Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see from [the doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta_data) Your object WC_Product_Simple inherit from WC_Data and then have a method  `get_data` You should consider to use this one to get your `sale_price` and `regular_price`

Here is your getter from docs :

```
/**
 * Returns all data for this object.
 *
 * @since  2.6.0
 * @return array
 */
public function get_data() {
    return array_merge( array( 'id' => $this->get_id() ), $this->data, array( 'meta_data' => $this->get_meta_data() ) );
}
```

If you want to use more accurate getter you can call :

`get_sale_price()`
`get_regular_price()`

And again here the woocomerce code for those :

```
/**
 * Returns the product's regular price.
 *
 * @param  string $context What the value is for. Valid values are view and edit.
 * @return string price
 */
public function get_regular_price( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'regular_price', $context );
}

/**
 * Returns the product's sale price.
 *
 * @param  string $context What the value is for. Valid values are view and edit.
 * @return string price
 */
public function get_sale_price( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'sale_price', $context );
}
```

You can find the whole code [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#278-286)

Comment: Thank you, the `get_data` method worked perfectly for me. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: You can try the other two there are more specific from what you want, don't hesitate to consult the docs, this is your bible now !

Comment: Thanks, they are more specific and a better use for me. Haha, indeed! I've got the link bookmarked now!